# Unable to execute Get-AzADUser as Managed Identity in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-managed-identity

I am unable to execute this line as a System Managed Identity on an Azure VM Powershell -

```powershell
Connect-AzAccount -Identity #--To connect using managed identity of the VM
$user = Get-AzADUser -ObjectId '****'
```

`$user` comes out to be null if I am using Managed Identity whereas I am getting valid `$user` if I use my microsoft account to connect.

How do I identify whether an object ID is an **AAD User** using Managed Identity running powershell on a VM?
The use case is I need to automatically remove users having access to AKV in production. For that I need to know if an object id belongs to a user and proceed with deleting role as needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you execute `Get-AzADUser` directly, you will get this error `Insufficient privileges to complete the operation`.

This is because you didn't assign an AAD role (for example **User Administrator**) to the managed identity of the VM. So it has no access to the AAD user.

You can assign the AAD role like this:

**Azure Portal** -> **Azure Active Directory** -> **Roles and administrators** -> enter "user admin" -> click on "User administrator".

[image]

Click on "Add assignments" -> **Select member(s)** -> enter the name of your VM or object id of the managed identity.

[image]

Then the managed identity of the VM can get the users through `Get-AzADUser`.

Comment: For me the Add Assignments button is grayed out, any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @AbhishekAnand You need to be a global admin of the Azure AD tenant. If you are not an admin, ask the admin of your company to do this for you.

Comment: I see, thanks! Seems like I'll need to go through a lot of SOX related processes to get this approval done. 
That being said, is there any easier way to do this.. To find out if an AAD object id belongs to a user or an SG, without having to use graph API?

Comment: @AbhishekAnand In fact, there are not a lot of SOX related processes. It's a basic permission / role scene use case. Why not just **Search user** or **Search groups** using the object id in Azure portal? Although you don't want to use Microsoft Graph, it's really easy to [query object by id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-getbyids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) in [Microsoft Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

Comment: Thanks, Allen Wu for your help! I was finally able to get Admin consent for my managed identity. It now has Directory.Read.All permission on Azure AD Graph.

Answer (score 1):

I raised a request to AAD Admin of my tenant to provide `Directory.Read.All` permissions to the Managed Identity App ID in Azure AD Graph (not Microsoft Graph).

Once the Managed Identity got the Admin Consent for this permission, I was able to get the users using `Get-AzADUser`.